# ob_get_clean and ob_get_contents return content to screen instead of putting it into variable when used with var_dump

Tags: php-5.3, php

I use this function for debugging:

```
function d($v,$tofile=null) {
    static $wasused;
    ob_start();
    var_dump($v);
    $dump = ob_get_clean();
    if (is_array($v)) $dump = preg_replace("@=>\n@",'=>',$dump);
    if (strlen($dump)>1000 or $tofile) {
        fileput('debug.txt',$dump,$wasused);
        echo n.n."strlen=".strlen($dump)."   >> debug.txt".n.n;
    }
    elseif (strlen($dump)<80) echo $dump;
    else echo n.n.$dump.n.n;
    $wasused=true;
}
```

the problem is it sometimes return content to console, particularly when this content is var_dump result on a big array,

anyone of you have seen this problem before ?

Comment: Just a heads-up in case you didn't know: you can also use `var_export($v, TRUE)` and `print_r($v, TRUE)` to debug the value a variable without using output buffering. That is, they both return strings without printing.

Comment: var_export shows a little less information than var_dump, for example it doesn't count arrays

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your `php.ini`:

```
implicit_flush = On
```

change it to this:

```
implicit_flush = Off
```

Comment: I had this option OFF all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Before assuming that there is a problem with var_dump itself, one would need to verify that fileput() does exactly what the question implies.